# Как сделать гамбургер-меню для мобильных устройств Java

Tags: java

..........................................................................

Comment: Старайтесь писать в теле вопроса что вы уже пытались делать, в чём возникли проблемы и приводите примеры кода.

Answer (score 4):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32614629/3212712) делается это так:

Берёте DrawerLayout и ActionBarDrawerToggle и настраиваете их нужным образом. Вот пример кода (внутри метода onCreate класса активити):

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

if (actionBar != null)
{
   actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
   mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.hello_world, R.string.hello_world)
   {

      public void onDrawerClosed(View view)
      {
         supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
         //drawerOpened = false;
      }

      public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
      {
         supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
         //drawerOpened = true;
      }
   };
   mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
   drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
   mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

Также надо добавить синхронизацию состояния в течении жизненного цикла приложения, добавив/переопределив вот эти методы в активити

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java или все-таки Android?

для Android проще всего заюзать Android Studio, создав активити выбрав тип Navigation, все сгенерируется само, потом можно что-то изменить, скопировать, портировать куда-то, скажем в устаревший eclipse